# How to pass "this" on to a callback function in a function I don't control?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, oop

I have an API call as such (in React):

```
class ClassName extends React.Component {

configuration(authorization) {
// Do a thing
}

componentDidMount() {

    window.method(
      ["openid", "email", "address"],
      this.onAuthorizationCallback
    );
}

  onAuthorizationCallback(authorization) {
// do something with this - referencing ClassName
this.configuration(authorization)
  }

}
```

My issue is that "this" - referring to ClassName, is not in scope. I'm not quite sure how to pass it on - I've looked into binding, call and apply, and I'm not sure that any of them work for my use-case, but that may just be a lack of understanding about Javascript scope.

Can anyone explain to me how I would reference "this" inside a callback function?

Comment: `() => this.onAuthorizationCallback()`

Comment: So this is definitely not passing the authorization variable that the original did

Comment: Oh, it takes an argument - so you just need to define it and pass it along `(authorization) => this.onAuthorizationCallback(authorization)`

Comment: Oh, got it. Thank you. Still getting used to ES6